# I am trying to pull tiles from mapbox to use for leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, leaflet, mapbox

I keep getting a 404 error but even after hours of trying to figure out what was wrong I haven't been able to figure it out. One message that I've seen is, "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute" Is there a way that I could access that attribute of the cookies I recieve from Mapbox?

```
   function mapInit() {
    let locationMap = L.map('map-container').setView([40.181270, -83.088779],15);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/15/20041/52741?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidHA4NTA1NTgzIiwiYSI6ImNrZzJ5dDNmNjA1bmYyc28zajRiZXpwb2kifQ.IdnR8H3QvoxD0I6dQi2oDA', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHA4NTA1NTgzIiwiYSI6ImNrZzJ5dDNmNjA1bmYyc28zajRiZXpwb2kifQ.IdnR8H3QvoxD0I6dQi2oDA'
}).addTo(locationMap);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a question?

Comment: I've clarified what I was asking a little and added some new info I found.

Answer (score 2):

Change your TileLayer code to:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHA4NTA1NTgzIiwiYSI6ImNrZzJ5dDNmNjA1bmYyc28zajRiZXpwb2kifQ.IdnR8H3QvoxD0I6dQi2oDA'
}).addTo(map2);
```

Comment: Took me a minute to spot the difference!